# How to convert dictionary to Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, dictionary

I am trying to convert a python dictionary to csv but it is not converting right.

I tried pandas to_dict method to convert

```
ref = db.reference('Order')
json_data = ref.get()
print(data)
```

Input Data is in this form:

```
{'3fGCr4RtRlMVLJOkHpkGgeeRuGq2': {'243': {'AddressType': 'Home', 'PaymentType': 'Cash on Delivery', 'Products': {'2169121631864': {'Image': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/', 'Name': 'Good Goodies Long Cake Red Velvet 32g', 'Price': 15, 'Quantity': 4}
```

I want to convert this data into tabular format.

Comment: dict or from list ?

Comment: from dictionary

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example as text (rather than image)?

Comment: @MohsinHussain Please post sample input and output. It makes it easier for the rest of us to understand and answer the question.

Comment: My data is in nested dictionary form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to convert dict to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
new_dict = {'key 1': 'value 1', 'key 2': 'value 2', 'key 3': 'value 3'}

In[33]:pd.DataFrame([new_dict])
Out[33]: 
    key 1     key 2     key 3
0   value 1   value 2   value 3
```

Comment: The data is in Nested dictionary form.

Comment: Can you include the expected output? Do your output has headers as :-
AddressType, PaymentType, Cash on Delivery, Products only.